# How do I exclude/rename some classes from import in Scala?

Tags: scala, scala-2.8

[Language FAQ](http://scala.sygneca.com/faqs/language#how-do-i-import) says

```
import scala.collection.mutable.{_, Map => _, Set => _}
```

should import all classes from package `scala.collection.mutable`, except `Map` and `Set`. But it gives me this error:

```
error: '}' expected but ',' found.
       import scala.collection.mutable.{_, Map => _, Set => _}
```

Is there still a way to do this?

Comment: Actually, it says this: `import scala.collection.mutable.{Map => _, Set => _, _}`

Comment: Yes, now it does: http://scala.sygneca.com/faqs/language?rev=1273682255&do=diff

Answer (score 98, accepted):

The  `_` has to be put at the end - not at the beginning:

*Exclude Map and Set from the import*

```
import scala.collection.mutable.{Map => _, Set => _, _}
```

*Exclude Set and rename Map to ScalaMutableMap*

```
import scala.collection.mutable.{Map=>ScalaMutableMap, Set => _, _}
```

See the detailed info in [Scala Refererence](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf#page=58), page 50, paragraph 4.7

Comment: "This is useful if there is a final wildcard in the same import selector list, which imports all members not mentioned in previous import selectors."